# not applicable for main.dart configuration flutter android studio emulator error

Tags: flutter, android-studio

In the android studio, I have installed an emulator. However, I can't use it. I couldn't figure out the issue and I need ur help.

[No selected device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzQDg.png)

[No connected device error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg0fu.png)

[flutter doctor output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvfUq.png)

[project structure SDK directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3LMA.png)

I can start the emulator, but I can not see my project there.

Answer (score 0):

In the no selected device bar there is an icon with a small phone , click on it , you will get a list of emulators , select your's

Comment: I didn't say that my emulator doesn't work. It works but can't see my project there.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue several time.

What fix this for me is to "Restart Flutter Daemon" (Double tap on shift in Android Studio then search for this action)

Comment: Tried but didn't work. Thanks for the reply.